# Using a proxy artist inside a legend, matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter((logngal),(logm200),c='r',label='$0.0<z<1.0$')
ax1.plot((logngal),(curve_y_1),'y',linewidth=2,label='$slope=%s \pm %s$'%(slope1,slope1_err))


ax1.fill_between(x_pred, lower, upper, color='#888888', alpha=0.5)
p1 = mpatches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="#888888",alpha=0.5)
ax1.legend([p1],['$1\sigma\/confidence\/limts$'])

fig2.show()
```

When I perform the above, **I only see `$1\sigma\/confidence\/limts$` mentioned in the legend.**

Whereas as you can see that I also call `label='$0.0<z<1.0$'` and `label='$slope=%s \pm %s$'%(slope1,slope1_err)` in `ax1.scatter` and `ax1.plot` respectively.

This does not get plotted in the legend.

**How do I add all the above three labels inside the legend?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to grab the `scatter` and `plot` artists as you plot them, and then feed the handles and labels from them to `legend`. For example, here's your code modified (with some sample data at the beginning just to get it to run):

`plt.plot` returns a list of `Line2D` objects, so if you read it as `pplot, = plt.plot(...)`, you unpack that one-item list.

You can then use `.get_label()` on `pplot` and `pscat` to give the labels to the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# Some things to make your script run when I don't have your data
slope1,slope1_err='this','that'
logngal   = np.linspace(0,1,20)
logm200   = np.random.rand(20)
x_pred    = np.linspace(0,1,20)
curve_y_1 = 0.5*(np.sin(logngal)/2.+np.cos(logngal))
upper     = np.sin(x_pred)/2.
lower     = np.cos(x_pred)
# end of sample data

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

pscat  = ax1.scatter((logngal),(logm200), c='r',label='$0.0<z<1.0$')
pplot, = ax1.plot((logngal),(curve_y_1),'y',linewidth=2,label='$slope=%s \pm %s$'%(slope1,slope1_err))

ax1.fill_between(x_pred, lower, upper,color='#888888', alpha=0.5)

p1 = mpatches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="#888888",alpha=0.5)

handles = [p1,pplot,pscat]
labels  = ['$1\sigma\/confidence\/limts$',pplot.get_label(),pscat.get_label()]

ax1.legend(handles,labels)

fig2.show()
```

[image]